# FM receiver With LM386 - Need a Preamplifier

Tags: receiver, frequency-modulation, preamp

I am building a hoppy FM Receiver and I created the Preamplifier stage 1 and linked it with the LM386 Stage and it goes OK but The output sound from the Speaker is weak so I tried to do some modifications to increase the sound with no luck.

**The question** is I want a Preamplifier stage to be placed before the LM386 for a louder volume

I tried to add another stage before the LM386 but My trials (all failed - the sound does not increase but it decreases)

The Source for the FM Receiver :
https://radiosvat.ru/beginner/5-fm-radio.html

The Source for different Preamplifier stages:
https://www.homemade-circuits.com/small-amplifier-circuit/

Attached is the FM receiver circuit currently working :
[image: FM receiver With LM368]

-All is fine and I can pick the FM Stations(Despite the whistle squeak, whistles for such a simple receiver )
-If I used earphone speakers the Sound is good no need for any preamplifiers, but I need to make it work with an 8Ohms speaker

-Kindly note I will not try to find another FM receiver, I am good with this one :)

-I want a simple transistor-based preamplifier circuit.

Comment: You don't need a preamplifier, you have a so called XY problem. Maybe you are unaware that you can configure the LM386 gain from 20 to up to 200.

Comment: Can you explain more about XY problem. I did so by adding a 10 uf between bin 1 and 8 but the noise was very very high, when I used a filter in the output pin as in some examples by using a 10Ohm and a capacitor , the noise disappeared but the volume was dropped i was not able to hear the voice out of the speaker so I went back to the original schema

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472690/simple-fm-radio-receiver-project So many bad projects where layout affects poor performance of a poor design

Comment: In order to get a good SNR, from adequate CNR, there needs to be adequate FM conversion gain of the input filter amplifier to from the steep filter skirt of an FM signal with high Q filter.  This converts FM to AM.  Poor Q results in poor SNR. Other issues cause a whistle from positive feedback leakage.  The transistor preamps here can only be expected to give a gain of 25 with impedance loading losses..

Comment: So any suggestions to minimize the SNR with minimal components or should I give up this schema?